# Get list of dependencies from browserify API

Tags: javascript, browserify

I am trying to write a browserify-aware Makefile, and to determine  the dependencies for my bundled build target, I would like to kindly ask browserify to list them.

What I already achieved:

```
browserify index.js --deps
```

will list them as a JSON, which I can parse, to extract the list. However I wonder if it would be more efficient if I tried doing this through browserify's API.

```
browserify(path.resolve('index.js'))
  .pipeline.get('deps').on('dep', (dep) => console.log('dep'))
```

This does not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a way to get the dependencies from the browserify API:

```
const through = require('through2')

const bundler = browserify('index.js')

bundler.pipeline.get('deps').push(through.obj((row, enc, next) => {
  // simply write the filename to the console
  console.log(row.id)
  next()
}))

bundler.bundle()
```

The benefit is that I don't have to buffer the whole json to stdout when I only want to parse the ids, which would eat a lot of memory for larger trees.